# Nested menu in table with laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I need to show nested notes if were exist into my table, I have worked it these way, it works only for first row, and I can't know what i did wrong.
this is my code:

```
<td>
  @inject('Common', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuditYearController')
  @if($Common->has_entry_note($entry->id) == 'true')
     <ul id="treeview1"><a href="#">الملاحظات</a>
     @foreach($entry_notes=$Common->get_entry_notes($entry->id) as $es)
       <li>{{ $es->text }}
           <ul>
               <li>{{ $es->suggestion }}</li>
               <li>{{ $es->clarification }}</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
     @endforeach
     </ul>
  @else
     لا يوجد ملاحظات
  @endif
</td>
```

and this is the result.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using accordion.

```
<td>
@inject('Common', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuditYearController')
@if ($Common->has_entry_note($entry->id) == 'true')
   @foreach ($entry_notes = $Common->get_entry_notes($entry->id) as $es)
      <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="e{{ $es->en_id }}">
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h6 class="accordion-header" id="head{{ $es->en_id }}">
            <a class="collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target="#one{{ $es->en_id }}" aria-expanded="true" 
            aria-controls="one{{ $es->en_id }}">
            <i class="si si-plus text-teal"></i><strong>{{ $es->text }}</strong></a></h6>
        <div id="one{{ $es->en_id }}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" 
             aria-labelledby="head{{ $es->en_id }}" data-parent="#e{{$es->en_id }}">
           <div class="accordion-body">
                 {{ $es->suggestion }}
                 {{ $es->clarification }}
           </div><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
  @else
    لا يوجد ملاحظات
  @endif
</td>
```

[image]